# Break anywhere when $r1 equals to string GDB

Tags: gdb

Is there anyway to break on `gdb` where `$r1` equals to a certain string
I know there is :

```
break [addr] if ((int)strcmp($r1, "hello")) == 0
```

But what to set in `addr` when I just wanna break when the `r1` is `"hello"` no matter the address?

Comment: ask on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Python api in GDB is very convenient to script such solutions. Although the api is a little "wild", I refer to [pwndbg](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg) on how to use the api. I wrote the following for x86_64 to break only when the first param matches "pol". Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/sudhackar/68e204654b4f4033b29736abfb4c2ee8)

```
import gdb

class MyBreakpoint (gdb.Breakpoint):
    def stop (self):
        rdi = int(gdb.parse_and_eval("$rdi").cast(gdb.lookup_type('uint64_t')))
        print("x(%x)" % (rdi)), 
        result = gdb.selected_inferior().read_memory(rdi, 10)
        if b'\x00' in result:
            result = bytearray(result).split(b'\x00')[0]
        if result == b'pol':
            return True
        return False

MyBreakpoint("x")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what is the difference between your script and 
break x if ((int)strcmp($rdi, "pol")) == 0" ? 

I would like to break anywhere not just X just break when r1 is equal to a string no matter in which function i am isnt that possible ?

Comment: iirc gdb has no such feature. However you can use Intel PIN and instrument on the instructions where r1 is changed. Your other option is just to fetch all the instructions which change r1 in a disassembler and set conditional breakpoints.